# MongoDB single $lookup / aggregate query to list users and the teams where the user assigned as a member

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to write a $lookup query example `User.aggregate([{ $match }]).lookup({...` to list users with extra key `_team` where the user is assigned as a member in any of the team. This is the example mongo collection -

1st Collection

```
# Users Collection - 
{
    "_id": "1",
    "name": "Sankhnad"
},
{
    "_id": "2",
    "name": "Shweta"
}
```

2nd Collection

```
# Teams Collection - 
{
    "_id": "1",
    "name": "Rock Team",
    "_members": [
        2
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "2",
    "name": "Star Team",,
    "_members": [
        1,
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "3",
    "name": "Yeh Team",
    "_members": [
        1,
        2
    ]
}
```

Now I want a single **$lookup / aggregate** query on the `users` and `teams` collection to list all users and their respective teams or a selected user and its teams where the user has been assigned in the `_members`.

The expected output for all users -

```
# Output - 
{
    "_id": "1",
    "name": "Sankhnad",
    "_teams": [
        {
            "_id": "2",
            "name": "Star Team",,
            "_members": [
                1,
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "3",
            "name": "Yeh Team",
            "_members": [
                1,
                2
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "2",
    "name": "Shweta",
    "_teams": [
        {
            "_id": "1",
            "name": "Rock Team",
            "_members": [
                2
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id": "3",
            "name": "Yeh Team",
            "_members": [
                1,
                2
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I really thank all of you for the support.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **$lookup** as follow from the users table as you want the associated teams of the users.

Note: The **_members** **id** should be **string** not **int32** for lookup. If it would not be string than **type** **conversion** is necessary.

```
db.users.aggregate([$lookup:{
  from: 'teams',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: '_members',
  as: 'teams'
}])
```

The same query using the pipeline of the lookup would like

```
db.users.aggregate[{
  from: 'teams',
 let:{ids:"$_id"},
 pipeline:[{
  $match:{
    $expr:{
    $in:["$$ids","$_members"]
  }
  }
 }],
  as: '_teams'
}])
```

Answer (score 1):

Query

- lookup can work on array/single value, and lookup happens if the array contains that value. (works like query `$eq` operator)
- because you have the "_id" in string and in array you have it as numbers `$toInt` is used also

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70381525-m)

```js
users.aggregate(
[{"$set":{"nid":{"$toInt":"$_id"}}},
 {"$lookup":
  {"from":"teams",
   "localField":"nid",
   "foreignField":"_members",
   "as":"_teams"}},
 {"$unset":["nid"]}])
```